# Why du doesn't return the right number for the disk added to instance in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have created a disk and added to an instance already, I SSH'ed into the instance and issue the following command and confirmed the disk has been added to the instance:

```
xenonxie@us-central1-a:~$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/

total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec 25 03:39 google-persistent-disk-0 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 25 03:39 google-persistent-disk-0-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec 25 19:38 google-persistent-disk-1 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec 25 03:39 scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_persistent-disk-0 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 25 03:39 scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_persistent-disk-0-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec 25 19:38 scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_persistent-disk-1 -> ../../sdb
```

The last line `scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_persistent-disk-1` is the disk I created/attached.

I like to validate the size of the disk (200GB) but it seems something wrong as I do not receive the result.

```
xenonxie@us-central1-a:~$ du -hc /dev/disk/by-id
0       /dev/disk/by-id
0       total
xenonxie@us-central1-a:~$
```

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't the du command till you how much space is used?  Perhaps you mean df to show you how much disk is free?

Comment: Thanks. `df -h /dev/disk/by-id` returns error: df: /dev/disk/by-id: No such file or directory, maybe the `/dev/disk/by-id` is not for `df`?

Comment: Many dimensions.  To see the raw disk partitioning ... use "fdisk -l".  To see the amount of used Linux file system data, use du on a mounted file system.  To see the amount of free Linux file system data, use df on a mounted file system.  Running "fdisk -l" should show you that the disk is partitioned for 200GB.

Comment: Thank you very much, just a finding here, because the underlying system is Debian for my case, to run fdisk, use `sudo fdisk`, can you please rephrase your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Thank you for the correction/comment on sudo for fdisk.  Hope you now have what you need.  If not, please post back further and we can always pick it up again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we create a disk in GCP and associate it with a Compute Engine, we may wish to ask questions about the nature of the disk.  To see the raw structure of the disk, we can use the [fdisk](https://linux.die.net/man/8/fdisk) command.  This will list the partitions and their sizes.  A good choice might be `fdisk -l`.  Since this is a low-level command, you might have to run it with `sudo fdisk`.

If you have mounted the disk as a file system, you can then use file system commands to examine the Linux filesystem nature.  Two commands of interest are [du](https://linux.die.net/man/1/du) to look at / examine disk utilization and another command is [df](https://linux.die.net/man/1/df) which shows how much disk is free.